# R - select cases so that the mean of a variable is some given number

Tags: r

I previously worked on a project where we examined some sociological data. I did the descriptive statistics and after several months, I was asked to make some graphs from the stats.

I made the graphs, but something seemed odd and when I compared the graph to the numbers in the report, I noticed that they are different. Upon investigating further, I noticed that my cleaning code (which removed participants with duplicate IDs) now results with more rows, e.g. more participants with unique IDs than previously. I now have 730 participants, whereas previously there were 702 I don't know if this was due to updates of some packages and unfortunately I cannot post the actual data here because it is confidential, but I am trying to find out who these 28 participants are and what happened in the data.

Therefore, I would like to know if there is a method that allows the user to filter the cases so that the mean of some variables is a set number. Ideally it would be something like this, but of course I know that it's not going to work in this form:

```
iris %>% 
  filter_if(mean(.$Petal.Length) == 1.3)
```

I know that this was an incorrect attempt but I don't know any other way that I would try this, so I am looking for help and suggestions.

Comment: No. Say you had 3 cases `c(1, 2, 3)` and filtered to mean of 2. How would it know if it's all cases, just 1 and 3, or just 2?

Comment: @caldwellst It wouldn't but I know the exact sample size, so if the sample size for your example was 2, it could only be `c(1, 3)`. Other combinations would produce either a mean of 1.5 or 2.5.

Comment: It sounds as though you want to find which 702 out of 730 participants have the mean that you found previously. In other words, which 702 participants have a sum of (702 * old mean). Since there are 2.8 * 10^50 ways to select 702 elements from a set of 730  you can't do this by an exhaustive search. Have you no other clues to go on?

Comment: @AllanCameron That is correct! I previously tried writing a `for` loop that would go through all possible combinations of participants, but that would take several trillions of years to compute.

Unfortunately I don't have any other clues, just descriptive stats for 20 variables. Is there any other approach I could take to solve this?

Comment: @J.Doe see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not convinced this is a tractable problem, but you may get somewhere by doing the following.

Firstly, work out what the sum of the variable was in your original analysis, and what it is now:

```
old_sum <- 702 * old_mean
new_sum <- 730 * new_mean
```

Now work out what the sum of the variable in the extra 28 cases would be:

```
extra_sum <- new_sum - old_sum
```

This allows you to work out the relative proportions of the sum of the variable from the old cases and from the extra cases. Put these proportions in a vector:

```r
contributions <- c(extra_sum/new_sum, old_sum/new_sum)
```

Now, using the functions described in [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59682706/split-a-set-into-n-unequal-subsets-with-the-key-deciding-factor-being-that-the-e), you can find the optimal solution to partitioning your variable to match these two proportions. The rows which end up in the "extra" partition are likely to be the new ones. Even if they aren't the new ones, you will be left with a sample that has a mean that differs from your original by less than one part in a million.